textscan doesn't work well with big files in Matlab?
I'm currently using the latest Matlab version on 16 GB RAM Mac.
I tried to perform a splitting of a really big cube file (100 GB) into smaller cube files with only 210151 lines per file using this code:
%% Splitting
% opening the result.cube file
fid = fopen(cube) ;
if fid == -1
    error('File could not be opened.');
end

 m = 1 ;

while ~feof(fid)
    % skip the alpha and beta density
    fseek(fid,16596786,0) ;

    % copy the spin density
    text = textscan(fid,'%s',210150,'Delimiter','\n','Whitespace','') ;


    % Prints the cube snap shot to the subdirectory 
    name = string(step_nr(m))+'.cube' ;
    full_path = fullfile(name1,name) ;
    fid_new = fopen(full_path,"w") ;
    fprintf(fid_new,'%s\n', text{1}{:}) ;
    fclose(fid_new) ;
    m = m+1 ;
end

fclose(fid) ;

save("steps","step_nr")

end

My problem is: Apparently, textscan is not suited for this kind of files. I also tried with line-by-line copying with fgetl, which on the other hand takes ages for a file of 100 GB. Is there a more efficient way to split the file?
I've read about fscanf and tried this:
tic;
fid = fopen('result.cube');
fgetl(fid) ; fgetl(fid) ;
f = fscanf(fid, '%d %f %f %f', [4 4]) ;
s = fscanf(fid, '%d %f %f %f %f', [5 192]) ;
n = fscanf(fid, '%f %f %f %f %f %f', [6 209953]) ;
fid_new = fopen("new",'w') ;
fprintf(fid_new, '%d %.6f %.6f %.6f\n', f) ;
fprintf(fid_new, '%d %.6f %.6f %.6f %.6f\n', s) ;
fprintf(fid_new, '%f %f %f %f %f\n', n) ;
fclose(fid) ;
t=toc

But my problem here is: s is not aligned in the individual file like in the big file. n is in decimals instead of for example E-02. I also tried to copy it line by line but it takes years. Any suggestions how to improve this? I want it to look like this:
enter image description here

Do you need to do this in Matlab? Can you not just use the split command-line tool?
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/split.1.html
This should do the job:
split input_file.txt --lines=210151

If you additionally want to skip (discard) the first 16596786 bytes of the input file:
tail -c +16596786 input_file.txt | split --lines=210151

To first split the input file and then remove the leading 16596786 bytes from each chunk:
split --lines=210151 input_file output_
for i in output_*; do tail -c +16596786  ${i} > ${i}.chopped; done


Does this also contain the for loop and extract periodically 210151 lines?

You don't need a loop. The split program simply takes an input file and splits it up every n lines or every n bytes, depending on how you call it. This will produce as many "chunks" (i.e. output files) as needed. In the example that I gave, it splits every 210151 lines. How this works in internally, that is totally up to the split implementation. You don't need to care.

Thanks! But as far as I understand it only chops off the first 16596786 bytes right? I would it also to chop the first bytes every time prior to collecting the lines I need.

Yes, in the above example we skip (discard) the first 16596786 bytes. Then, the remaining data is split up into n separate chunks (files), so that each chunk contains (at most) 210151 lines. The last chunk may actually be shorter, if the total number of lines is not an exact multiple of 210151. It would also be possible to first split the file into several chunks (either by max. number of lines per chunk, or max. number bytes per chunk), and then discard the first x bytes (or lines) of each chunk.

Oh yeah, the second approach will be actually better because I want to discard the first few bytes in every chunk.

As an alternative answer, you could use the following Python script:
import os
with open('input.txt', 'rb') as input:
    size = os.fstat(input.fileno()).st_size
    chunk = 0
    while input.tell() < size:
        # skip the next 16596786 bytes
        input.seek(16596786, 1)
        with open(f'output-{chunk:02X}.txt', 'wb') as output:
            # copy up to 210151 lines to new file
            for _ in range(210151):
                if len(line := input.readline()) < 1:
                    break
                output.write(line)
        chunk += 1


So are you saying that there's no way for Matlab to handle this? I'm unfortunately not really familiar with Python.

I'm no Matlab expert, but what you asked for sounds more like a task that you can easily accomplish with the standard Unix command-line utilities; or, at most, can be done with a few lines of shell script. Since the tools like split and tail work "stream-based" (won't load the entire file into memory at once), they can easily process gigabytes of data. The Python script is yet another simple way. Script should work as-is, just run with python3 script.py. Maybe adjust the file names as needed.
